# Icons not shown for Imported UTIs, even if an application is the default

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

I have a Cocoa app for which I have created an Exported UTI and some Imported UTIs, with corresponding Document Types in the Info.plist file. All files can be opened in my app from Finder as expected.

Despite specifying an icon for all the file types however, only the file type corresponding to my exported UTI has the icon shown in Finder. All the imported UTIs have their icons unchanged, even if my app is the default for that file type.

Some other files in the file system do have icons that represent an associated application, sometimes that is the default application for that file type, sometimes it isn't.

Under what circumstances are the icons for the imported UTIs shown?

Here are the relevant parts of the Info.plist file.

```
<key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>public.mp3</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>mp3</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon</string>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Mp3</string>
    </dict>
</array>

<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Mp3</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.mp3</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: That can sometimes happen because the Launch Services database values may be cached by a running process of the system. Try to restart your computer and see if that helps.

Comment: Nope. What's the expected behaviour? When should a file show an icon provided by an application?